# D3: How to access an attribute of a previous item

Tags: d3.js

I am using D3 to plot a rectangle for each object in an array, the height of the rectangle being dependant on the 'Size' property of the object. These rectangles are stacked on top of each other. I currently set the y position by summing the 'Size' of each subsequent rect that gets plotted - but this seems wrong - and I was wondering if there was a better way to do this, such as accessing the 'y' attribute of the previous item (and how?) or another way...

[image: Stacked Rectangles]

This is what the essence of my code looks like. There is a link to the fiddle below.

```
    var cumY = 0;
    var blocks1 = sampleSVG.selectAll("rect")
    .data(fpp)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .sort(SortBySize)
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("opacity", blockOpacity)
    .style("fill", function (d) {return d.Colour})
    .attr("width", 80)
    .attr("height", function (d) {return d.Size})
    .attr("x", 5)
    .attr("y", function (d, i) {
    var thisY = cumY;
    cumY += d.Size;
    // perhaps I could just return something like d.Size + previousItem.GetAttribute("y") ???
    return thisY;
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ninjaPixel/bvER3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky do! You're right that keeping track of the cumulative height 'seems wrong' - it works now but it isn't very idiomatic d3 and will get pretty messy once you start trying to do something more complicated.

I would try using d3's built in [stack-layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Stack-Layout) which was created solve this problem. You might want to start working off of [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768) and posting an updated fiddle if you get stuck. Good luck!